# Checking whether space should be printed in the middle or at the end in for loop?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, primes

I am trying to give info to my program whether it should print space or not.

My code looks something like this, and its printing spaces at the end (which is not what I want)

```
void function(int given_limit)
{
    int current_num = 2;
    while (given_limit > 1)
    {
        if (given_limit % current_num == 0)
        {
            if (current_num == 2)
            {
                printf("%d ", current_num);
            }
            else if (current_num == 3)
            {
                printf("%d ", current_num);
            }
            else if (current_num == 5)
            {
                printf("%d ", current_num);
            }
            else if (current_num == 7)
            {
                printf("%d ", current_num);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d ", current_num);
            }

            given_limit /= current_num;
        }
        else
            current_num++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

In main() I am calling it something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int given_limit = 13;
    for (int i = 0; i <= given_limit; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t\t", i);
        function(i);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any tips and help.
One of the ideas is maybe to store it in an array.

Comment: Print a space before each number instead, and improve on the use of the preceding `\t` with for example `printf("%-16d", i);`

Comment: Replace `"%d "` with `" %d"` throughout.  It'll leave you with a blank after the two tabs, but that should be OK.  You could consider using `"%-15d"` for the call to `printf()` in `main()`; that would give you 15 characters (digits and blanks) before the blank from the `" %d"` printing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler   The main problem is, when i try switching between  `"%d "` and    
 `"%d "`, for example for number 2, instead of getting      ` [0;33m2[0m`      I get this       `[0;33m·2[0m`  , so space is again in the middle, eventhough we cannot see differene when compiling

Comment: `num_of_fields` should be `given_limit`.

Comment: @Franck Actually in code it is `given_limit`, and the code I posted is working. Problem are spaces at the end.. but thanks for noticing

Comment: @th3coder: Your comment about "instead of getting `[0;33m2[0m` I get this `[0;33m·2[0m`" is puzzling.  I don't see those characters.   It looks like you might be working with escape codes so the `\[` is escape, but you don't show the backslash, or it gets omitted by the Markdown formatting.  And I'm not clear where the 'compiling' comes in — you can only see the difference (which I'm still not clear about) when the code is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced spaces with asterisks for better visibility and removed the redundant if-elements. Then I introduced a flag which indicates whether it is the output of the first factor or a later one. In front of each later one we put the space (or asterisk).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
void function(int given_limit)
{
    bool is_first_factor = true;

    int current_num = 2;
    while (given_limit > 1)
    {
        if (given_limit % current_num == 0)
        {
            if (is_first_factor) {
                is_first_factor = false; // not first anymore
                // print nothing
            } else {
                printf("*"); // between two factors
            }            
            printf("%d", current_num);

            given_limit /= current_num;
        }
        else
            current_num++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int given_limit = 13;
    for (int i = 0; i <= given_limit; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t\t", i);
        function(i);
    }
}
```

```
$ gcc spacing.c
$ ./a.out      
0
1
2               2
3               3
4               2*2
5               5
6               2*3
7               7
8               2*2*2
9               3*3
10              2*5
11              11
12              2*2*3
13              13
$
```

Comment: include stdbool.h and use bool and true/false

Comment: I normaly use a variation of this. I start with `sep = "";` before the loop and use `printf("%s%d", sep, current_num); sep = " ";`. This has 2 benefits: 1) no branch, 2) I can use `sep = separator;` where `separator` is an argument to the function so I can choose the separator.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above move the space character to in front of each prime factor and then align the output to take the initial starting space character into account.

This example also skips unnecessary factors.

```
/* primefactors.c

*/

#include <stdio.h>

void primeFactors(int number)
{
    printf("  %2d   ", number);

    // only test factors <= sqrt(number) 
    // skip even factors > 2
    
    int factor = 2;
    while (factor <= number / factor) {
        if (number % factor == 0) {
            printf(" %d", factor);
            number /= factor;
        }
        else if (factor == 2){
            factor = 3;
        }
        else {
            factor += 2;
        }
    }

    // at this point number equals the greatest prime factor
    printf(" %d\n", number);
}

int main (void)
{
    int max = 45;

    printf("\nnumber  prime factors\n");
    printf("------  -------------\n");

    // skip 0 and 1 which have no prime factors
    printf("  %2d\n", 0);
    printf("  %2d\n", 1);

    for (int i = 2; i <= max; ++i) {
        primeFactors(i);
    }
      
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good alternative, thanks